# Ubuntu 18.04 and Nvidia GPU driver resolution issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

My Desktop has got 6GB Nvidia GTX 1060 which has the compatible recommended nvidia driver as nvidia-396.
Tried installing it using

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-390
sudo apt install nvidia-kernel-source-396
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

Please refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032938/trying-to-install-nvidia-driver-for-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts) thread for more details.
and disabled noveau using this

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
sudo update grub2
```

But I am having the resolution problems...800X600 resolution...even xrandr says so that it is the maximum possible resolution.

The same is happening to my Dell XPS 9560 laptop which has Nvidia 1050 GPU. I followed the same steps for it.
I am having Ubuntu 18.04.

what could be the issue? It seems 18.04 release is yet not that stable for nvidia.

Comment: I installed nvidia-390 on ubuntu-mate 18.04  and didn't had to do anything. It just worked. Maybe issue is with nvidia-396.

Comment: The "nomodeset" is only used with nouveau, to allow X to run (at maybe lower resolution) until you set up the Nvidia drivers, then it is removed.

Comment: The issue still exists or resolved? I have the same issue

Comment: All the issues resolved now.