# Downgrade nvidia 396 to 390 in Bionic

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm having trouble downgrading my nvidia drivers from 396 to 390. If I purge all of the nvidia drivers, then do `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390` it still installs the 396 version. Is there any way to force it to install the older version?

I've tried `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390=390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1`, but that gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-390 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 is to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there some way of telling it to use the older versions of the dependencies?

It's becoming very frustrating as the 396 drivers appear to be causing problems with any games I have installed, whereas the 390 worked fine, but I can't seem to rollback and no option for the older version appear in the Software/Updates app either.

Thanks

**Update:**

As requested, here's the output of `apt policy nvidia-390` following installation via PPA:

```
nvidia-390:
  Installed: 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Candidate: 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Also, here's the output from the actual installation (`sudo apt install nvidia-390`):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms libnvidia-cfg1-396 libnvidia-common-396 libnvidia-compute-396
  libnvidia-compute-396:i386 libnvidia-decode-396 libnvidia-decode-396:i386
  libnvidia-encode-396 libnvidia-encode-396:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-396
  libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386 libnvidia-gl-396 libnvidia-gl-396:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-396 libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 libxnvctrl0
  nvidia-compute-utils-396 nvidia-dkms-396 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-driver-396
  nvidia-kernel-common-396 nvidia-kernel-source-396 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-396 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dkms libnvidia-cfg1-396 libnvidia-common-396 libnvidia-compute-396
  libnvidia-compute-396:i386 libnvidia-decode-396 libnvidia-decode-396:i386
  libnvidia-encode-396 libnvidia-encode-396:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-396
  libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386 libnvidia-gl-396 libnvidia-gl-396:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-396 libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-390
  nvidia-compute-utils-396 nvidia-dkms-396 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-driver-396
  nvidia-kernel-common-396 nvidia-kernel-source-396 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-396 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396
0 to upgrade, 28 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 16.1 kB/88.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 365 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-driver-390 amd64 396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1 [8,072 B]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-390 amd64 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [8,044 B]
Fetched 16.1 kB in 0s (85.5 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 287858 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-cfg1-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-cfg1-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-common-396.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-common-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnvidia-compute-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-compute-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-decode-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-decode-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-encode-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnvidia-encode-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-fbc1-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-fbc1-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-390
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-390
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-ifr1-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libnvidia-ifr1-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxnvctrl0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libxnvctrl0_396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxnvctrl0:amd64 (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-396.
Preparing to unpack .../16-nvidia-kernel-source-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-396.
Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-kernel-common-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-dkms-396.
Preparing to unpack .../18-nvidia-dkms-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-396.
Preparing to unpack .../19-nvidia-compute-utils-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-396.
Preparing to unpack .../20-nvidia-utils-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396.
Preparing to unpack .../21-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-396.
Preparing to unpack .../22-nvidia-driver-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-390.
Preparing to unpack .../23-nvidia-driver-390_396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-390 (396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-390.
Preparing to unpack .../24-nvidia-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-390 (390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../25-nvidia-prime_0.8.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package screen-resolution-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../26-screen-resolution-extra_0.17.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking screen-resolution-extra (0.17.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../27-nvidia-settings_396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.8) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nvidia-fallback.service → /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-fallback.service.
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.17.3) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Loading new nvidia-396.24.02 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 103) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 105) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 103) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-396:i386 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-390 (396.24-0ubuntu1~pop1) ...
Setting up nvidia-390 (390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3pop2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

and finally, the output from `glxinfo | egrep "version"`:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 396.24.02
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 396.24.02
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 396.24.02
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

Comment: You have to totally purge before instaling new nVidia driver. list drivers available, same list as system settings,  software updates,  additional drivers or last tab
`ubuntu-drivers devices` Mine is a bit older card an it only shows 390 & 340.  did you also add the ppa for newest drivers? Did you only install from Ubuntu repository, not directly from nVidia? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I have purged all the old drivers, and am using the PPA. I managed to get it to install eventually using aptitude instead of regular apt, but then I ran into problems with black screens after login. Annoyingly I didn't have that issue before with the older drivers. I'm beginning to think Bionic is a total disaster---I've had nothing but problems since I installed it.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the driver from the NVIDIA web page and installing it manually?  I just had to go through that process for a much older driver - 304 - which is the only one that manages the temperature properly on an old laptop I have running Bionic.  I did eventually get it to work.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I haven't tried that, but will do so now. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a page that was helpful to me when I did it.  You can ignore the patch steps, that was specific to the 304 driver.  One thing this page leaves out is the necessity to kill the x session before running the install script.  https://adufray.com/blog/2018/06/02/nvidia-304-127-on-bionic

Comment: Seems that installing it directly from the .run file results in me booting to a black screen. Can't seem to install it manually at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't install the 390 version of Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu repos, because the `nvidia-390` package pulls the 396 drivers.

But the good news is that you can install the 390 driver from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

Run

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

Comment: I've followed this, but still end up with 396 installed. If I do `apt-cache showpkg nvidia-390` it shows that 390.67 is the latest version available, and that it is from the PPA, but when I install it I still get 396.24. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add output of `apt policy nvidia-390` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: I've added that, and also the output from the actual installation and  `glxinfo` showing that it's still using 396.

Comment: You probably installed a driver without using apt form a .run file.

Comment: Or you need to freeze the version in synaptic.

Comment: I did, but a much older version that I've since removed (using the `-uninstall` flag on the .run file). When I purge the drivers, the system has only MESA drivers installed, so there's definitely nothing left from nvidia. I notice if I do a search in APT, it shows "Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390" for the 390 driver, which leads me to think it's pointing to the 396 one even on the PPA :(

Comment: That's true. The dependencies lead to 396. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: And did you reboot? I looked into repos and it looks that this answer should work. But you need to reboot.

Comment: This is odd, because I use that PPA, and I get 390. In fact I just got an update to it yesterday.  `apt policy nvidia-driver-396` gives me `Installed (none)`  The same on -390 gives me  `Installed: 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1`

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, it was 390.59 prior to the update.  The apt history log shows stuff like this `(390.59-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1, 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)`

Comment: My .bash_history shows that after the 18.04 upgrade I did the process in your answer except for the last line.  I did `sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings` Could that make a difference?

Comment: If you ran `sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'` all should be removed.

Comment: I'm very OK with where I am. I was trying to see why it didn't work for @DylanParry

Comment: I think what's happened is that I have another PPA that is conflicting with it. I just noticed from the output of `apt policy nvidia-driver-390` that it was getting the 396 driver via the System76 Pop Theme's PPA, although why on Earth it was doing that when it's only supposed to be a theme, I don't know. I have removed that PPA and it seems to be installing correctly now.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.  You did well to remove that ppa, it's got everything and the kitchen sink in it. https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/pop/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=

Comment: `nvidia-390` didn't work for me. `nvidia-driver-390` did