# Broken package fix after installing 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: nvidia, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, 18.04

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 I got a black screen, then from the terminal, I tried to uninstall Nvidia.

From Grub, I pressed 'e' and added nouveau.modeset=0.

I am able to successfully log in, but if I try to fix the broken packages

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Terminal get stuck in `Building initial module for 4.15.0-24-generic`

The complete output after sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-24-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Removing old nvidia-390.67 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 390.67
Kernel:  4.15.0-24-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 390.67
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-390.67 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-24-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-24-generic
```

Comment: Wait a while for it to build the module.  DKMS modules (kernel driver embedding modules) can sometimes take **a long time** to compile and build.  Took almost 30 minutes for a display link driver on an older system, so...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue, after doing the update through Software and Updates. Then I followed this link

[Trying to install nvidia driver for ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032938/trying-to-install-nvidia-driver-for-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts)

One should check this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
blacklist amd76_edac
options nouveau modeset=0
```